# How to tell if a class is an internal class or a user class?

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to tell (programmatically, obviously) if a given class is an **internal class** (such as `DateTime`) or a **user class** (`class MyClass`)?

In case you wonder (and I'm sure you do), this is because [ReflectionClass::newInstanceWithoutConstructor()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstancewithoutconstructor.php) throws an exception when used on internal classes, and as I'm writing a library to deep-copy objects, it must skip these internal classes.

Yes, I could just catch the `ReflectionException`, but this exception is thrown for other reasons as well (such as a non-existing class), and is not thrown for all system classes. so it's not exactly fulfilling my needs.

Comment: Why exactly would one want to skip a constructor?

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: You'd never want to do that in everyday coding. But libraries do that to hydrate objects loaded from a persistent storage, or in my case, to deep-copy an already instantiated object.

Comment: Even if I'm going to populate it with external data, running the constructor cannot be wrong IMHO. You can never know what kinds of internal structures need to be initialized.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast That's how ORMs such as [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) re-instantiate objects loaded from the DB (you don't want to call your constructor every time your object is loaded from the database, no more that you'd want your constructor to be called when you unserialize your object). PHP 5.4 introduced `newInstanceWithoutConstructor()` because such use cases do exist.

Comment: As far as I remember, `__wakeup()` is called when unserializing an object, which is something similar to a constructor in my eyes. But fair enough, I see the point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A cleaner solution than using `shell_exec` whould be to use **reflection**:

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('SomeClass'); 
if($reflection->isUserDefined()) {
   // 'SomeClass' is not an PHP internal
}
```

Instead of an string (`'SomeClass'`) you can also pass an object. For more information lookup [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and
[`ReflectionClass::isUserDefined()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isuserdefined.php) in the PHP Manual

Comment: Oh, beautiful! One could `array_filter` over `get_declared_classes` and get a nice list of user defined classes that way

Comment: Since he already has created a reflectionClass, this is obviously the very best solution.

Comment: Woah, I missed this obvious solution. This is the one. Thank you!

Comment: According to : http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isinternal.php we cant distinct if a class is in the core or form an extension

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question, one way I can think is by checking the namespace, for example all of your classes would be defined under `namespace MyApp` and then check:

```
if(class_exists('\\DateTime')){
    continue;
}
```

Kind of ugly, I know.

Comment: I've thought about this, and although it's true that all *my* classes are namespaced, I can't guarantee that nobody will try to use this code on non-namespaced classes unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Food for thought, based on Дамян Станчев's suggestion:

You could just run a PHP interpreter via `shell_exec()` that will spew out `get_declared_classes()`. Capture the output of that, and you should have a "clean" list of system classes.

---

Extending Mogria's answer, this one should work just fine (don't give me credit for this though, as it was Mogria's answer that got it right ;-)):

```
function getUserDefinedClasses() {
    return array_filter(get_declared_classes(),
                        function ($class) {
                           $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
                           return $reflectionClass->isUserDefined();
                         });
}
```

Comment: Good workaround, only issue I can see with that is it relies on `shell_exec` which some systems may prevent.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to imitate the reflection behaviour by extending the class you're trying to copy, and overriding the `__construct` function:

```
<?php
    class MyClass extends ExtendingClass {
        public function __construct() {
            /* Override default constructor */
        }
    }
?>
```

Which could essentially be made dynamic by using `eval`:

```
<?php
    function newInstanceWithoutConstructor($class) {
        $className = $class . "Extended" . rand(0, 99999999);
        while (class_exists($className)) {
            $className = $class . "Extended" . rand(0, 99999999);
        }
        eval("class " . $className . " extends " . $class . " { public function __construct() { } }");
        return new $className();
    }
    $newInstance = newInstanceWithoutConstructor("DateTime");
?>
```

**HOWEVER**: Using `eval` can be useful in this case, but also reveals a rather large security-hole if anything user submitted can be submitted in any way to change the contents of `$class`. If you understand these limitations, and security implications, you should be able to use this.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to *instantiate* this internal class at all costs, I just want to *skip* it if it happens to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `get_declared_classes()` in the beginning of your script, store the data in an array and then do an `array_diff()` with the stored data and the response from `get_declared_classes()` and check if the class you're checking is in the difference using `in_array()` ?

Comment: Have you tested it? It will already contain ***declared*** classes from all script.

Comment: I can't control when my code will be executed (it's a standalone library), so at the time I call `get_declared_classes()`, it might already contain user classes unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://codepad.org/avboUJnt) prints out all the classes with your classes seeming to be at the end of the list. Maybe this can help.

Comment: Unfortunately `get_declared_classes()` returns user classes as well!

Comment: Yeah, but they are at very end ( = not sorted by their name), so maybe you could just fetch those at the end. Sorry if it wasn't helpful :|

Answer (score 0):

What about storing [calling get_declared_classes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) data **before** any autoloading/include/require is made and later checking class name in this storage?

Comment: Same remark as for Дамян Станчев: I'm afraid I can't control when my code will be executed as it's a standalone library!